# map not defined in my react after bring data from database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks, array.prototype.map

i have a website with api to get movies,i have a user in my web and this user can like a movie and get him into his favorite. then he have a commponent that call favorite and i want to do there a get request from my data base and bring him the title of my movie.after he get the title i do in my useeffect an api request to get the poster and all the details of the movie and then i wanna to show it in my favorite useing map function.
but i have a problem
my map dosent work or if it work he dosent bring the data from the api

this is the favorite componnent

```
import { getAllFavorite } from "../../service/favServics";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import PageHeader from "../common/pageHeader";
import FavoriteChiled from "./favoritechild";
function Favorite() {
  const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState([]);
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  async function getAll() {
    const { data } = await getAllFavorite();
    setFavorite(data);
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${data[i]}&apikey=aea06659`;
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const responseJson = await response.json();
      const obj = responseJson.Search[0];
      if (responseJson.Search) {
        setMovies(obj.Title);
      }
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getAll(favorite);
  }, []);
```

This is the return of favorite component

```
<div className="row">
  {movies.map((movie) => (
    <FavoriteChiled movie={movie} />
  ))}
</div>
```

this is the child componnent

```
function FavoriteChiled(props) {
  let { movies } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <div key={movies.imdbID} className="image-container d-flex justify-content-start m-3">
        <img src={movies.Poster} alt="movie"></img>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

the console error

```
favorite.jsx:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at Favorite (favorite.jsx:32:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)`
```

or this error

```
favorite.jsx:32 Uncaught TypeError: movies.map is not a function
    at Favorite (favorite.jsx:32:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)`
```

Comment: *"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"* - This means `movies` is `undefined`.  *"movies.map is not a function"* - This means `movies` is not an array.  In either case, when you debug, what is the observed runtime value of `movies`?  It looks like the only place you update it is: `setMovies(obj.Title)`  Which means that `obj.Title` is (1) `undefined` or (2) not an array.  You'll need to debug to observe what data you're receiving from your service.

Comment: hey the only thing i cant understand is why movies all the time empty and i cant find in my debug where the problem,for a sec i did solve this and the 2 movies that come from the db was showen but the secend movie was on the first one so i didnt see them right

Comment: Well, if the problem is that the data you're receiving isn't what you expect, then a good debugging step would be to observe the data you're receiving.  Observations are always better than assumptions.  You can log the value of `responseJson` to the console and see what it actually contains.  Same with the value of `obj` and the value of `obj.Title`.  Knowing what data you're receiving will help you understand why that data isn't what you expect.

Comment: hey i did what u say and now it work the problem that in my database i have not 2 movies so the api need to bring them both in the UI but its look like he bring 1 of them and them bring the other one on him and discard the first one

Comment: It's not really clear... Do you mean to say that there is no longer a problem to solve?  If that's the case then you should probably delete this question, since it no longer serves any purpose.  But if there *is* still something wrong, please elaborate.